# Hi. Today I tried to sent coins to Mostyn Lewis Investment. But I sent it somewhere else?Where?

Tags: zero-confirmation

And here I sent it.Could you help me please. This is the adres I have sent it to;bc1qtpqqawlvye7elp3sp3snmfts7lfkqtduefe8jq so I do not know where I can find help.And where the money are sent to. I wanted to send it to Mostyn Lewis Investment. But it showed me from coinbasewallet that I do not have enough. Then I put all I had. And also checked it in blockchain explorer. A lot of confirmation and still confirming..where was this sent to?(back to me or I lost it) And I really do not know. If sb knows the answer even is bad, please answer me...Thanks

Comment: I sent it and do not know where to..I see that transaction in blockchain/explorer. I sent this bitcoins from Coinbase wallet. Please hulp me. I do not know what to do, and where is the money sent.I wanted to send it to Mostyn Lewis Investment. Scanned the QR code. And know nothing more...Sb van help me? Please. That was about 721euros.

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question to include additional information instead of adding comments. Putting that address into any [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) shows what has happened. About 721 EUR worth of BTC was sent from 
bc1qtpqqawlvye7elp3sp3snmfts7lfkqtduefe8jq to bc1qpc3d32x4ujwkpc06etu97fxvleplsk5nc0aw3y on Tuesday at 15:21 UTC. --- That is all anyone can tell you.

Comment: Ok. Everybody can see..but what does it mean? I have already posted that question above. Sorry then. And what then..noone knows..Thanks for comment..probably I lost it..

Comment: Are you using [the Coinbase app or the Coinbase wallet?](https://wallet.coinbase.com/faq/). The first is [custodial](https://news.bitcoin.com/the-difference-between-custodial-and-noncustodial-cryptocurrency-services/) and so you must talk to Coinbase. The second is non-custodial - in which case, as well as the receiving-address you should know the sending-address and the transaction-id. Adding those to your question might help people here to work out an answer.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick is saying that all we can know is that money was successfully sent to that address.  Presumably it's the same address that was encoded in the QR code you scanned.  If you were expecting Mostyn Lewis to do something after you sent the money, e.g. credit your account or respond in some other way, you have to take it up with them; we can't help you with that.

Comment: I'm sorry you sent money to a scam.

Comment: I have both. Coinbase app and Coinbase wallet. Money was sent from phone app wallet.I contacted Coinbase without answer. And about Mostyn Lewis I do not know what exactly happenned. At first when I scanned the QR it showed me that there is not enough money, what was not true. Many times. Scanning is easy. I do it always. But here was sth that I do not understood. I was confused and tried to send first not all cryptyo, but then i sent all. And I had to authenticate.After sending the portfolio was empty. I aprecciate your cares. Coinbase is informed. Blockchainexplorer too.Tomorow  I write more

Comment: Hello. I have contact Coinbase. They told me that they had looked and I have to wait about 7 working day...thank you all..i will let you know later then..have a good weekend